Mirroring language/subdirectory
Our Drupal 10 site has several language/region versions, with translatable content displayed as:
www.example.com/en-us/products/example
www.example.com/en-au/products/example
www.example.com/en-us/seminars
www.example.com/en-au/seminars
and so on.
Our New Zealand office wants to add a site for NZ, which content-wise would be nearly identical to the en-au site.
We were quoted 3 months work by our development agency who manage the site.
In the interest of due diligence I'm here to ask:

For content with >95% in common with en-au, is adding the /en-nz/ site common procedure?
Is there another way, e.g. to mirror the site via server settings, accept requests to /en-nz/ and serve /en-au/ content?

Thank you very much for your advice.

Question 1 is a business/design choice and really outside the scope of questions that can be answered here.
For question 2, mirroring a site by server settings (via a server redirect or CDN) is certainly possible, but then this is not a Drupal question and so also out of scope for this site.
However, can this be done in Drupal?  Of course, but it depends on how your Drupal site is configured to handle multiple languages.
If en-au is the default language, adding an en-nz site that allows content to be customized and then uses en-au as a fallback for everything else should be super simple, because that is the multilingual subsystem's standard behavior. (Add en-nz in the languages admin section and you are done.)
However, if another language (e.g., en-us) is the default, then you need to add a custom fallback for en-nz to en-us. This could be custom code or something like the Entity Language Fallback module.
I don't know the scale of your site or other factors that would make things complex that resulted in a three-month estimate, but the work of creating a NZ language variant that falls back to the AU language variant is likely to take less than a day. So I would definitely check back with the agency and make sure they have understood the requirement; it may be much easier than they have estimated.

Hi Patrick, thanks very much for the response.
I will certainly look into the Entity Language Fallback module, and just to clarify about the scale of the site, we have almost 500 pages/nodes translated into 20 languages. We are in year 2 after renewing the site to Drupal from a prehistoric custom PHP site.
Our team is non-technical, so used to doing things in a less than systematic way, hence trying to find a smarter alternative this time.
Thanks again.

Sure, the Entity Language Fallback module should enable you to copy the Australia content to NZ, and then you only need to "translate" the pages you want to change for NZ.  There may also be issues with menus and things if the content isn't 100% mirrored, but I imagine that module can get you most of the way there if they are close to exact copies.
